# What solvents can I use to dissolve Epichlorohydrin rubber and Chloroprene Rubber

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, solubility, solutions, chemical-potential

I am working with Epichlorohydrin and Chloroprene Rubbers and I would like to cast films of 2 mm at most. The solvents I have in my lab are DMSO, THF, DMF, Acetone, Ethanol and Propylene Carbonate. Has anyone made films with these rubbers/elastomers?

Update: I have dissolved epichlorohydrin rubber in Acetone, but the casted films are easily deformed when removing from my casting dish. Now the only challenge is how I can cure them in an acetone medium

Answer (score 0):

Regarding chloroprene rubber, a friend dug up the following information: CR is synthesized by polymerization in aqueous solution and can be purchased as a latex. That solution is alkaline because it tends to give off $\ce{HCl}$ in storage. The solid is described as 'soluble in aromatic solvents', but the gel component may be insoluble.

Source is: Handbuch für die Gummi-Industrie, edited by Bayer AG, Geschäftsbereich Kautschuk. 1991.

Answer (score 0):

For chloroprene (neoprene), you might try [chlorinated solvents](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/chloroprene), e.g., methyl chloride (chloromethane).

Epichlorohydrin has "Inferior resistance to oxygenated solvents," according to [River Rubber](https://www.grandriverrubber.com/products/materials/). That's a bit vague: diethyl ether? acetone? toluene? [Tahco Rubber](https://rahco-rubber.com/materials/eco-epichlorohydrin-hydrin-rubber/) also states it has poor resistance to chlorinated solvents.

BTW, epichlorohydrin rubber is slow to vulcanize.